# How to create directory c++ (using _mkdir)

Tags: c++, directory, mkdir

Today I did a lot of research online about how to create a directory on C++
and found a lot of way to do that, some easier than others.

I tried the `_mkdir` function using `_mkdir("C:/Users/...");` to create a folder. Note that the argument of function will be converted into a `const char*`.

So far, so good, but when I want to change the path, it does not work (see the code below). I have a default string path `"E:/test/new"`, and I want to create 10 sub-folders: `new1`, `new2`, `newN`, ..., `new10`.

To do that, I concatenate the string with a number (the counter of the `for`-loop), converted into char using `static_cast`, then I transform the string using `c_str()`, and assign it to a `const char*` variable.

The compiler has no problem compiling it, but it doesn't work. It prints 10 times *"Impossible create folder n"*. What's wrong?

I probably made a mistake when transforming the string using `c_str()` to a get a `const char*`?.

Also, is there a way to create a folder using something else? I looked at `CreateDirectory();` (API) but it uses keyword like `DWORD HANDLE`, etc., that are a little bit difficult to understand for a no-advanced level (I don't know what these mean).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<direct.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int stat;
string path_s = "E:/test/new";

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    const char* path_c = (path_s + static_cast<char>(i + '0')).c_str();
    stat = _mkdir(path_c);

    if (!stat)
        cout << "Folder created " << i << endl;
    else
        cout << "Impossible create folder " << i << endl;
    Sleep(10);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i + '0'` won't work very well when `i == 10`. Perhaps you should use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead?

Comment: And the [Windows `CreateDirectoryA` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya) is really easy to use: Pass the path as the first argument, and a null pointer as the second.

Comment: You might be interested in new (C++17) [file system library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), you wouldn't rely on (non-standard!) `mkdir` any more...

Comment: Does "E:/test" exist?  I'm pretty sure `_mkdir` will only create one level of directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `(path_s + static_cast<char>(i + '0'))` creates a *temporary* object. One whose life-time ends (and is destructed) just after `c_str()` has been called.

That leaves you with a pointer to a string that no longer exist, and using it in almost any way will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Instead save the `std::string` object, and call `c_str()` just when needed:

```
std::string path = path_s + std::to_string(i);
_mkdir(path.c_str());
```

Answer (score 7):

If your compiler supports c++17, you can use filesystem library to do what you want.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(){
    const std::string path = "E:/test/new";
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i){
        try{
            if(fs::create_directory(path + std::to_string(i)))
                std::cout << "Created a directory\n";
            else
                std::cerr << "Failed to create a directory\n";\
        }catch(const std::exception& e){
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that under Linux, you can use the mkdir command as follows:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
... 
const int dir_err = mkdir("foo", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
if (-1 == dir_err){
    printf("Error creating directory!n");
    exit(1);
}
```

More information on it can be gleaned from reading `man 2 mkdir`.