# How can i create a dir in Documents folder? [C++]

Tags: c++

Im trying to create a directory , or a subdirectory in the Documents folder.

```
 PWSTR   ppszPath;    // variable to receive the path memory block pointer.

    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &ppszPath);

    std::wstring myPath;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        myPath = ppszPath;      // make a local copy of the path
    }

const wchar_t* str = myPath.c_str();
    _bstr_t b(str);
   
    int status = _mkdir(b+"\\New");
```

As you can see , I'm trying to create a new folder named "New" in Documents Folder.
The path to the documents is correct but the dir is not created.

Comment: Off topic but... why go through all that rather than simply use [`std::filesystem::create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory)?

Comment: First of all your code has some code smells. Like you only set `myPath` if `SUCCEEDED(hr)` returns true. But the rest of the function is executed either way. So maybe `SHGetKnownFolderPath` didn't succeed and therefor the rest of the code operated on an empty string.

Comment: I will change that thanks , the documents path is shown tho , i tried displaying it in debug mode

Comment: The other thing, that is probably not ideal is the usage of two different string classes `std::wstring` and `_bstr_t`. You probably only need one and can remove the other.

Comment: If it still don't work, look at `status`. It should contain information why the call to `_mkdir` failed.

Comment: Also I googled `_mkdir`. The parameter of `_mkdir` is not `_bstr_t` it is `const char *`. But you intially had a `const wchar_t *`, therefor you probably should use `_wmkdir`. Also ditch the `_bstr_t` and only use the `wstring`. Write `str += L"\\New";` followed by `int status = _wmkdir(str.c_str());`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create directory c++ (using \_mkdir)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358730/how-to-create-directory-c-using-mkdir)

Comment: G.M.'s comment is not off topic at all. `std::filesystem::create_directory` would be the standard, portable answer here. If you are asking for a specific API, please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is using `_bstr_t` to avoid using Unicode, the new path is converted to ANSI and will be invalid unless the original path was ANSI, (or ASCII to be guaranteed)

Just pad `L"\\New"` and wide string functions to solve the problem.

You also have to free `ppszPath` as stated in [documentation](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=SHGetKnownFolderPath)

```
std::wstring myPath;
wchar_t *ppszPath;
HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &ppszPath);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
{
    myPath = ppszPath;
    CoTaskMemFree(ppszPath);
}//error checking?

myPath += L"\\New";
std::filesystem::create_directory(myPath)
//or _wmkdir(myPath.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) class understands Unicode just fine, so you don’t need to mess with any helpers there. Also, you need to check *both* function results to determine success or failure:

```
bool success = false;
PWSTR documents_path = nullptr;
if (SUCCEEDED( SHGetKnownFolderPath( FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &documents_path ) ))
{
  using namespace std::filesystem;
  success = create_directory( path{ documents_path } / "new_folder" );
  CoTaskMemFree( documents_path );
  documents_path = nullptr;
}
```

The result of the operation is indicated in the variable `success`.

I would personally separate the functions of obtaining the user’s Documents folder and the directory creation into two separate functions, but the above will do just fine.