# How can I create a folder in C++ that is named using a string or char?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, mkdir

I'm trying to create a folder with a custom name for each user that will logged in but it doesn't work. Can you please help me? I'm a beginner and it's quite difficult.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string user = "alex";
    _mkdir("D:\\Programe\\VS\\ATM\\Fisiere\\" + user);
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to make the folder in the same way I make the files, but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358730/how-to-create-directory-c-using-mkdir

Comment: You might use more modern [`std::filesystem::create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_mkdir` is an older function which takes a C string as it's parameter. So you have to convert the `std::string` that you have into a C string. You can do that with the `c_str` method. Like this

```
_mkdir(("D:\\Programe\\VS\\ATM\\Fisiere\\" + user).c_str());
```

This code creates a `std::string` by appending the path with the `user` string and then calls `c_str` on that string and then passes the result of that to `_mkdir`.